# Windows Server Firewall, How to block network traffic to a specific IP address

Tags: firewall, sql

For some reason I cannot explain my SQL server is sending a bagillion 'EXEC sp_exec' calls to another DB on the network and I cannot find out why. I cannot restart either servers so in the meantime I would like to use the firewall to block traffic from exiting the servers if the network address is the other server.

For example, if Server A want to send to Server B then I would like to configure the firewall to prevent this from happening. Of course the IP addresses to Server A and B are known.

I attempted to use the firewall customer feature to set a outbound rule to prevent remote ip addresses. But when I wireshark it the traffic is still there. I have the rules enabled and I did the same rule for inbound and outbound traffic.

Any suggestions?